# Quickest way to copy the CSS from HTML markups

Tags: html, css, firebug

For example, when you open Firebug and select an HTML element, the CSS styles that affect this element will show up on the right panel.

If this element has no child, copying its CSS styles is easy. But sometimes the element has lots of descendant elements and they have CSS styles defined on them as well.

What is quickest way that you know of to copy the CSS from HTML markups?

Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good addon with Firefox named HTML validator and uses Tidy algo for validating. The addon has an option for cleaning up the page code and thus generates the css automatically. You can just copy them out.